# My animated images are always uploaded in reverse in Blender Video Editing

Tags: animation

I rendered 150 images via EEVEE and named them BlenderAnimation001 to BlenderAnimation150. And in the original folder they are in the right order from 1 to 150, but however I input them in Sequencer they are reversed, from 150 to 1. I tried shift select from 1 to 150, and from 150 to 1. I saw some options from older versions of Blender they were some tickboxes to reverse but now I can't find them. Thanks!

Comment: You’ve checked the side panel of the file browser? Sometimes it starts out collapsed.

Comment: Checking the Placeholder tickbox did it right. Thanks!